# Two generalizations of the Verblunsky Theorem

Tags: cv.complex-variables, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, geometric-measure-theory, quaternions

I learned from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06455)  about   [the Verblunsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials_on_the_unit_circle#Verblunsky%27s_theorem).

My question  is that: What kind of generalizations of this theorem is availlable?

In particular I am interested in the following two possible generalization:

1)Does every  arbitrary sequence $\{\alpha_n\} \in \mathbb{D}_4$ determine a unique probability measure on $S^3=\partial \mathbb{D}_4$?Can a queternion computation help us for such a generalization?

2)For which kind of sequence $\{\alpha_n\} \in \mathbb{C}^2\simeq \mathbb{C}P^2 \setminus \mathbb{C}P^1 $ we would obtain a unique probability measure on $S^2=\mathbb{C}P^1=\partial \mathbb{C}^2$?

To what extent can the method of  consideration of isometric group of the hyperbolic  disck in the above paper be generalized in order to answer to each of the above two questions?